# Detect changes before SubmitChanges()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

Settings: asp.net mvc web app with azure sql db, EF codefirst.
When submitting changes (by the user) in a single record to values in several fields (coming form a viewModel) in a db table (A) my code must make changes in another table (B).

Changes in table B, only must be made when a certain field in table A also is changed.

Is there a way to detect whether a value of a certain field has changed before the changes are actually made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `DbContext` subclass, override `SaveChanges` and look specifically for `A` entities of which the specific property is modified:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var aEntries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries<A>()
                       .Where(e => e.Property(a => a.SomeProperty).IsModified);
    foreach (var entry in aEntries)
    {
        // apply changes to B
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Side note:

From a viewpoint of single responsibility and semantics, this is not my preferred way of handling such scenarios. `SaveChanges`'s task is, well, to save changes. One would not expect it to do anything else. It's easy to forget that the code is even there and it's not an obvious place for others to look for code during maintenance or bug fixing.

It gets worse when the added code potentially causes side effects. I would be very careful with changing any context state in `SaveChanges` -- and that's exactly what I think "apply changes to B" is going to do. I'd rather do these modifications where it matters: in the code where `A` is modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can override SaveChanges in your DbContext class, and inspect the entities to be changed from the ChangeTracker:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
   var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<MyList>();

   if (changeSet != null)
   {
       // Add checks
   }
   return base.SaveChanges();
}
```